# ListView Items changed automatically in Fragment android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

when I scroll the listview the items changed automatically, in other word an item override other item's view like : when I click on favorite button other items has been changed like this 
example:

[the item that I clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94sxJ.jpg)

[I didn't click on this item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHFNh.jpg)

here is my code :

CustomListAdapter.java :

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    boolean isVoter;
    public CustomListAdapter(Context c ) {
        this.context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.date_view,null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.vote = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vote);

        }else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        isVoter = newsItemArray.get(position).isVoter();

        viewHolder.vote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!Utility.isNetworkAvailable(context))
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.no_network, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    voteBtn( position);

            }});
        return convertView;
    }


    public void voteBtn(int position){
        if ( !isVoter  ) {

            viewHolder.vote.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
        }
        else{

            viewHolder.vote.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
        }
        isVoter = !isVoter;

    }
}

private class ViewHolder{
    ImageButton vote ;

}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return newsItemArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return newsItemArray.get(position).getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

}
```

date_view.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/newsCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#fff"

        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/newsimage1"
                    android:layout_width="45px"
                    android:layout_height="45px"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/newsname"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Fox News."
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2 day ago"
                    android:textColor="@color/listsub1"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/more"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/more"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sourceNews"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/news"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Trump’s Plan for AmericanMade iPhonew Wold Be Disastrous. Trump’s Plan for AmericanMade iPhonew Wold Be Disastrous"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/listtext"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/newssub"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Why even a President Trump couldn’t make Apple manufacture iPhone in the state."
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/listsub1"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/votes_num"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#f40000"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/vote"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/star"
                    android:background="#00ffffff"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

                <!--
                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/vote"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/star"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/share"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Share"
                                    android:textColor="@color/background_material_light"/>
                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/comment"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Comment"
                                    android:textColor="@color/background_material_light"/>
                -->
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

isVoter and viewHolder should not be global variables within the Adapter. Meaning, you are not actually changing whatever member is returned by newsItemArray.get(position).isVoter()

Try adding the position to the ViewHolder object. Then pass the ViewHolder object into the constructor of the viewHolder.vote.setOnClickListener. Within the OnClickListener you can then call

```
isVoter = newsItemArray.get(viewHolder.position).isVoter();
newsItemArray.get(viewHolder.position).setVoter(!isVoter);
```